# What is the most efficient way to add keys with empty values to dictionary?

Tags: python

I use `ordered_set = dict()` to create ordered set. The values are not important. Test is whether the key was already added only. Ordered set is a set of unique values where the order of adding is maintained.

```
if node not in ordered_set:
  ordered_set[node] = None # ordered_set[node] = False or ordered_set[node] = '' or ordered_set[node] = 0
  f1()
else:
  f2()
```

What is the most efficient way to add keys with empty values to dictionary? Maybe there is a better way to implement ordered set?

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(listofkeys)`? Suppose, `listofkeys` is `[1, 2, 3]`, `dict.fromkeys(listofkeys) -> {1: None, 2: None, 3: None}` Instead of `None` you can specify your own default value `dict.fromkeys(lst, False)` would set values to `False`

Comment: Why not just do the assignment, without the if?

Comment: There is logic after verification and also logic for else. It is just part of a code.

Comment: So that check would also have to be done before the `setdefault`, right?

Comment: yes, check if node is in the ordered set and then call function and mark node as visited (add to the set)

Comment: Hmm, then it's really rather strange that you accepted that.

Comment: Why? It confirms my initial thoughts: 'So in terms of raw time to compute, the original poster's method appears more efficient in terms of time and the use of the builtin .setdefault()'

Comment: @OlegDats That wasn't there when you accepted it, was only added 35 minutes afterwards.

Comment: yes, but pointing to `setdefault` helped me to understand that set values to `None` is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an approach. In later versions of Python (3.6+, I think), the order with which keys are added to a dictionary is maintained (the order of the keys in the dictionary could not be assured in earlier versions of Python).

The method `.setdefault()` is built into Python dictionaries and is designed for the use case you are faced with: check to see if a key exists and if not, create the key and set a default value.

```
mydict = {1: True, 2:True, 5: True}

for key in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    mydict.setdefault(key, None)
```

yields

```
{1: True, 2: True, 5: True, 3: None, 4: None}
```

In the above, notice that the order of the keys is maintained ... the first three keys already existed and other keys (3 and 4) are added in a specific order and the order is maintained.

Because the default behavior of `.setdefault()` is to set the new key to `None` automagically, so we can simplify the code in this way:

```
for key in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    mydict.setdefault(key)
```

### Measuring efficiency:

One of the comments raises a great point about "efficiency" and not gonna lie, my approach was aimed at the developer's efficiency (i.e. using built in tools to keep code shorter, simpler, easier to understand). But let's look at what is happening under the hood in terms of code efficiency (i.e. time to compute):

Here is a simple benchmark that shows the relative speed of computation. We start by making `mydict` and a version of `mylist` with a much larger number of entries, most of which will not be present in the dict.

```
In [26]: %%timeit mydict = {1: True, 2:True}; mylist = list(range(1000000))
    ...: for key in mylist:
    ...:     if key not in mydict:
    ...:         mydict[key] = None
    ...: 
29.6 ms ± 613 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [28]: %%timeit mydict = {1: True, 2:True}; mylist = list(range(1000000))
    ...: for key in mylist:
    ...:     mydict.setdefault(key)
    ...: 
49.8 ms ± 715 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

We see that for the code that tests for the presence of the key in `mydict` first, we get a shorter time to complete. If we use the builtin method `.setdefault()` we see a longer time to complete (potentially because the function call might be expensive).

So in terms of raw time to compute, the original poster's method appears more efficient in terms of time and the use of the builtin `.setdefault()` might be considered by some to be more efficient in terms of developer time/mental effort. YMMV.

Comment: `dict().setdefault('s')` by default produces `{'s': None}`. Default value is `None`. I suppose it is the most efficient.

Comment: How much more efficient than `mydict[key] = None` is this? What were your benchmark results?

Comment: Oh wow, didn't expect the OP's to be that much faster. As I asked under the question, I'm not convinced they actually need the membership check before assigning, and I suspect leaving it out would make it faster even if most keys *are* already members. Anyway, you could make yours faster by storing `mydict.setdefault` in a variable and then using that instead. Could you add that to the benchmark?

Comment: Hmm, how does this timing work? Is initialization of the dict and list done as setup, before the measuring begins, or is it included in the time? And is it done before each of the 10 loops or just once? If just once, then in the 9 last runs, nothing gets added to the dict (and thus the OP's only has "half the work").

Comment: @KellyBundy The `%%timeit` function (as used within IPython) does everything on line one (initializing `mydict` and `mylist`) as setup and does NOT count that as part of the timing. I do not have a complete understanding of all the nuances of `%%timeit` and so cannot answer your more in-depth questions. Sorry, my friend.

Comment: What happens if you move the dict initialization out of the setup (into the timing)?